# add code automatically for any article/post

Tags: blocks, nodes

I built a Drupal website with a custom theme, but in the last stand I need to add a specific code after any post/article published on the site. For example:

article 1

code

article 2

the same code...

The pinpoint is that I don't know how to take a reference of a single post/article to include it in a buckle to add this code.

Comment: How do you insert "article 1" ? Do you use a node display ? In this case you should modify the node template in your theme.

Comment: I need insert the article 1 trough the add content menu (admin menu). But when it show in the "content" region need add a specific code in any article.

I don't understand how y can reference all articles in the code (a hook?) of the region for implement the specific code.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to **create a block** and add your code to it if it's html or javascript code. Then for **Show block on specific pages** select only on the listed pages and add `articles/*` This will affect all the pages that have articles in their url.

If it's php, you will need to **create a custom page tpl** file.

go to drupal/sites/all/themes/mythemename/templates and add **page--articles.tpl.php** This will affect all the pages that have articles in their url.